# Git:Adding error adding a second github account "ssh: Could not resolve hostname github-secondUser"

Tags: git, github, git-svn

I'm following the instructions on this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fnSRBRiQIU8&feature=youtu.be) of how add second github account. But I'm getting this error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github-secondAccount: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Here is what I have done.

I add it a second sshkey:

```
id_rsa
id_rsa.pub
id_rsa_secondAccount
id_rsa_secondAccount.pub
```

And also created a config:

```
#first account
        Host github.com
        HostName github.com
        User git
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

#secondAccount account
        Host github-secondAccount
        HostName github.com
        User git
        IdentityFile id_rsa_secondAccount


echo "# myNewRepo" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin git@github-secondAccount:myUSer/myNewRepo.git
git push -u origin master
```

But at the moment of `git push -u origin master` I'm getting this error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github-secondAccount: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Any of you knows what I doing wrong or how can fix this?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL should be `github-secondAccount:myUser/myNewRepo.git` (no need for `git@`)

Make sure your `~/.ssh/config` file is protected as 600.
And the second `IdentityFile` should be `~/.ssh/id_rsa_secondAccount`.

Finally, make sure `id_rsa_secondAccount.pub` (public key) has been published to `myUser` SSH keys setting page.

Comment: you mean the permission should be `600`?

Comment: What you mean `(public key) has been published to myUser SSH keys setting page`?

Comment: @user2924482 I mean: https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.13/user/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/

Comment: @user2924482 yes, 600 for the files within ~/.ssh, 700 for ~/.ssh itself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37626619/6309

Comment: I have publish the key and set the permissions but still have the same error.

Comment: @user2924482 check if your ~/.ssh/config file has LF end of line characters, not crlf (https://stackoverflow.com/q/18084456/6309). Then copy in a gist (https://gist.github.com/) the output of `ssh -Tv github-secondAccount` (just `github-secondAccount`, not `github-secondAccount:xxx`: remove the confidential parts (like actual servername or ip address) You should see a Welcome message: https://help.github.com/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection/

Comment: @user2924482 did you find what was missing in order to make it work?